# Python: dividing a float by a variable

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general.

I'm trying to do

```
angle = 360.0/nrOfObjects
```

where nrOfObjects is defined by a input window.

I'm getting:

```
# Error: line 7: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'unicode'
```

How do I divide a float by a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
angle = 360.0/float(nrOfObjects)
```

or this if your input should be only integer number

```
angle = 360.0/int(nrOfObjects)
```

By default `input()` and `raw_input()` return str or unicode depending on user input

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `nrOfObjects` is a Unicode string and not a number.

You need to convert it to float first:

```
angle = 360.0/float(nrOfObjects)
```

Comment: Or to an `int`, depending on what value `nrOfObjects` represents (given the name, I would assume it's integral).